# Looping through folders in batch file and converting folder names to dates and checking for oldest date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I’m trying to do something probably simply for you but I don’t know how to do it. I have a folder (say D:\Backup) where I place my backups daily using robocopy. There are several subfolders inside the backup folder named in the MM-DD-YYYY formats (i.e. 02-21-2014, 02-22-2014, etc.). I would like to loop through these folders and find the oldest date then rename it to today’s date and use the newly renamed folder for my robocopy backup batch file.

Comment: Good luck with this.  The members of the site will probably be a lot more helpful if you show some work you have tried and any issues you ran into.  Just asking for code (very broad) is not going to get much help.

Comment: This task would be very simple if you use `YYYY-MM-DD` folder name format which sort properly in a folder.  You would find that too when viewing them in a standard explorer window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@echo off&cls

set SearchFolder="D:\Backup"

::FOR NT
rem for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set "$today=%%a-%%b-%%c"
::FOR XP
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date:~4%') do set "$today=%%a-%%b-%%c"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd %SearchFolder%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir/b/ad') do (
set "#%%c%%a%%b=%%a-%%b-%%c"
)
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do (
set "$older=%%a"
goto:next)

:next
::Renaming the oldest folder
echo Oldest Folder = [!$older!]
echo Today Folder  = [%$today%]
ren !$older! %$today%

::Here your robocopy command. The today's date is in %$today%
```

You can then use %$today% in your robocopy command.

Comment: Oldest Folder = [12-31-2011]
Today Folder  = [11-Fri 04-2014]
The syntax of the command is inc
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Check my EDIT for XP !

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me sachadee
I didn’t see anywhere where I can define the folder to search so I added the cd followed by the location I want to search to the beginning of the code (i.e. cd C:\backup\) so that the code would search that folder. However it looks like it worked partially as this is what I got:
Oldest Folder = [12-31-2011]
Today Folder  = [11-Fri 04-2014]
The syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: OK for the CD c:\backup. Did you try with the modificated code for XP ?

Comment: I'm using XP for testing but the code will run on windows server 2012. I tried your XP code and I get an error: The system cannot find the path specified.
Oldest Folder = [1--]
Today Folder  = [11-04-2014]
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: My folders are named month-day-year like this MM-DD-YYYY (example: 05-28-2014 for May 28 2014)
Is there is a way to have a variable that will hold the folder to search? (i.e. set SearchFolder=D:\Backup)

Comment: OK for the Path Variable. Try the code again with the `pushd`

Comment: Thanks so much sachadee. I think we’re almost there with one issue left: the new folder name was formatted as DD-MM-YYYY and I want it to be formatted as MM-DD-YYYY (i.e. it was named 11-04-2014 and I want it to be named 04-11-2014

Comment: thanks so much sachadee. this worked! will the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion affect any of my other code? Also, If I use it for windows server 2012 should I use the NT line instead of the XP line?

Comment: You just have to test the output of a simple `echo %date%` at the command prompt. If the output is : `Fri 11/04/2014` use the XP version. If the output is just a date without the day : `11/04/2014` the you have to use the NT version.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

Echo ********************************************************
echo    Autor:  
echo    Datum: %date% um %time%
echo    Zweck: 
echo    Vers.: 
Echo ********************************************************


Echo ******************************************************** >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log
echo    Autor:                        >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log
echo    Datum: %date% um %time%                   >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log 
echo    Zweck: Backup von Ordnern                 >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log 
echo    Vers.: 1.0                        >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log
Echo ******************************************************** >> D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log

pause

echo Um das Backup zu starten bitte beliebige Taste druecken...

pause >nul

robocopy D:\Austausch D:\Backups\Files /e /m /a-:SH /LOG+:D:\Backups\LOGS\Logifle_%date%.log

echo Das Backup wurde erfolgreich abgeschlossen! Mit beliebiger Taste fortfahren.

pause>nul

echo Um das Logfile auszudrucken, geben Sie bitte folgendes Wort ein: "Print" Ansonsten können Sie das Programm mit exit beenden.

set /p Print=

IF %Print% == Print (
    echo Drucker wird gestartet
    print /d:\\Servername\Druckername D:\Backup\LOG\Logdatei_%date%.log
    pause >nul
    Sie können das Programm nun mit einer beliebigen Taste beenden.

) else (
pause )
```